# scramble (random permutation) of image pixels within a boolean mask in Python (PIL)

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, shuffle

I want to scramble, i.e., randomly permute the pixels of an area delimited by a boolean mask, in this case only the **area of the face** (omitting the background).

The code to do random permutation on the whole image works, but when I apply it to the masked array, it also changes the color... How to perform the shuffling alongside only the non-color axes?

```py
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np 

response = requests.get("https://www.4dface.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/4DFM_sample2.jpg")
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
    
img.show()
```

[image]

```py
def _shuffle_2D(x):
    return _shuffled(_shuffled(x.swapaxes(0, 1)).swapaxes(0, 1))

def _shuffled(x):
    """Return a shuffled array. Because python does it in-place."""
    np.random.shuffle(x)
    return x

array = np.array(img)
PIL.Image.fromarray(_shuffle_2D(array))
```

[image]

Below, the same is applied to a masked array: as one can see, it also shuffles the colors...

```py
# Get mask
mask = np.array(img.convert("L")) != 255
array[mask] = _shuffle_2D(array[mask])
PIL.Image.fromarray(array)
```

[image]

Any pointer is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't researched if there are any shuffle methods that allow axes to be set or excluded from shuffling, but one fast way might be to convert each RGB888 pixel into a single `uint32` prior to shuffling, then split back into RGB888 afterwards. As the 3 bytes will then be packed together into a single entity they won't get separated from their little friends.

You can do this extremely quickly with `np.dot()` like this:

```
# Make a single 24-bit number for each pixel, instead of 3x 8-bit numbers
u32 = np.dot(RGBarray.astype(np.uint32),[1,256,65536])
```

So here's what I am suggesting in concrete terms:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO
import numpy as np 

def _shuffled(x):
    """Return a shuffled array. Because python does it in-place."""
    np.random.shuffle(x)
    return x

response = requests.get("https://www.4dface.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/4DFM_sample2.jpg")
img = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))
array = np.array(img)

# Get mask of non-white pixels
mask = np.array(img.convert("L")) != 255

# Combine RGB888 pixels into a single 24-bit entity
u32 = np.dot(array.astype(np.uint32),[1,256,65536])
u32[mask] = _shuffled(u32[mask])

# Now split 24-bit entities back into RGB888
r = u32 & 0xff
g = (u32 >> 8  ) & 0xff
b = (u32 >> 16 ) & 0xff
array = np.dstack((r,g,b)).astype(np.uint8)
res = Image.fromarray(array)
res.save('result.png')
```

[image]